# Under what conditions is $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim_{y\to\ 0} f\left(\frac{1}{y}\right) $

Tags: calculus

Under what conditions is $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim_{y\to\ 0} f\left(\frac{1}{y}\right) $ true? I'm having trouble understanding the specific instances in which the variable of a limit may be changed. Does the function have to be continuous? Does it have to be defined at the point of evaluation, etc.

Is there a way for me to generalize this to a stronger result for arbitrary change of variables in the limits?

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? $\mathbb R$ or $[0, \infty)$?

Comment: Taking $x = \frac{1}{y}$ then as $x\to \infty$ we have $y\to 0$ with $y\geq 0$ so if you change the last limit to $y\to 0^+$ then it's always true.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim_{y\to\ 0} f\left(\frac{1}{y}\right) $ if and only if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) =\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)   $.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a related and more general phenomenon (though it does not apply to your specific question):

Suppose $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x \to \alpha}g(x) = c$ for some function $g$. Then
$$\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = \lim_{x \to \alpha}f(g(x)).$$

Since  $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L$, for every real number $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a real number $\tau > 0$ such that
$$\vert f(x) - L \vert < \epsilon$$
whenever $\vert x - c \vert < \tau$. Pick $\epsilon > 0$. By $\lim_{x \to \alpha}g(x) = c$, produce $\delta > 0$ such that $\vert g(x) - c \vert < \tau$ whenever $\vert x - \alpha \vert < \delta$. Then
$$\vert f(g(x)) - L \vert < \epsilon,$$
completing the proof.

Comment: This "generalization" does not apply (at least directly) to the case of the question, because $\lim_{y\to\ 0} \frac{1}{y} $ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The usual $\lim$ notation implies that the limit is taken by any path and exists only if only one result is obtained.

For example, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x$ is said to be nonexistent since two different results, $-\infty$ and $\infty$ are obtained, depending on whether does $x$ approach $0$ along the real line from its positive or negative part.

Hence, if you need $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}f\left(\frac1x\right)$ to exist, $f$ has to have the same values on infinity, regardless the direction, i.e.
$$\forall_kf(\infty)=f(k\infty).$$
Obviously, that value would also be equal for the positive direction $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$.

An example of $f$ that satisfies the property is $\arctan|x|$.